# Handle nested stack navigator with react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Is there a way to consolidate headers from nested StackNavigators?

I'm trying to tree out my routes into something such as this to group the navigators together

```
Route1_Screen1

Route1_Screen2

__Route2_Stack

........Route2_Screen1

........Route2_Screen2

........__Route3_Stack

................Route3_Screen1

................Route3_Screen2

........Route2_Screen3

Route1_Screen3
```

etc...

Is it possible to go back from Route3_Screen2 to Route3_Screen1 to Route2_Screen2 to Route2_Screen1 to Route1_Screen2 to Route1_Screen1 using the headerBack button? Or is this way of doing routes wrong and I'm misunderstanding how stacks work?

Heres a little snack to explain what I'm trying to accomplish https://snack.expo.io/ryZH__qG4

Comment: Why are you using so many nested stacks? We (React Navigation team) recommend to keep nesting navigators to the minimum. It can also cause perf issues on Android.

Comment: I separate the navigator as much as possible for reusability and maintenability, if there is something that I misunderstood, please tell me. In this case, imagine the `_Route3_Stack` is the user's preference stack navigator. I would like to reuse it anywhere in my application.

Comment: They are for controlling how you screens look and animate, not for code organization

Comment: If my _Route3_Stack is containing something like 10 screens, I just don't want to make code duplication in each navigators that needs that screens. How to avoid this ?